# Plink failure on Windows 7 x64

Tags: ssh, putty, windows-7

Trying to use plink for a project and running into problems on Windows 7 x64. It simply goes to a blank line and hangs there. On a 32-bit XP development machine it runs as expected. We have tried XP compatiblity mode but it did not help.

Comment: Are you connecting to an opensolaris machine by any chance? What happens when you use standard putty?

Comment: We were connecting to a "SpamAssassin Virtual Appliance" which is Linux CentOS based I believe running on VMWare Server. It looked like PuTTY, or maybe it was specifically plink, just wasn't campatible with Windows 7 64bit but we were worried it would have the same issue on Windows Server 64bit OSes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to run commands through a simple PHP page. The connection was internal to our network and we weren't worried about encryption, just remotely triggering a command and getting the output. There must have been another command line scripting tool we could have used but the approach we took ended up being very simple and met our needs.